# all statements in javascript function not being executed

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

In the following function:

```
function EVOLVE1()
{
  if(ATP>=evolveCost)
  {
  display('Your cell now has the ability to divide.');
  display('Each new cell provides more ATP per respiration.');
  ATP = ATP - evolveCost;
  document.getElementById('cellscount').innerHTML = "Cells = " +cells;
  document.getElementsById('ATPcount').innerHTML = "ATP + " +ATP;
  document.getElementById('dividebtn').style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById('dividebtn').innerHTML = "Divide(" + divideCost + " ATP)";
   }
  else
  {
    display('Not enough ATP.');
  }
}
```

When it's executed, only the first 4 statements are executed. The last 3 lines have no effect whatsoever (i.e, a button with display:none isn't made visible, the paragraph isn't changed and the text in the button isn't changed either). I have no idea why this is happening. Also, display() is a simple function that changes a p within a div as such:

```
function display(x)
{
  var z = document.getElementById('centretext').innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('centretext').innerHTML = z + "<br>" +  x;
}
```

So I don't think it's causing the issue.
The HTML:

```
<div id="left" class = "format">
        <button class="buttonformat" id = "respirebtn" onclick="respire()"> Respire </button>
        <button class="buttonformat" id = "evolvebtn" onclick="EVOLVE1()"></button>
        <button class="buttonformat" id = "dividebtn" onclick="divide()"></button>
        <p id = "lefttext">
        </p>
      </div>
```

The CSS:

```
#evolvebtn
{
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top:450px;
  left:5px;
}

#dividebtn
{
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  left:5px;
  top:-30px;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the console? Might be an error in your `ATP = ATP - evolveCost;` statement if any of the variables is an invalid type for instance.

Comment: "a button with display:none isn't made visible..." that will make the button *not* visible. Also `getElementsById` is not a function, which is probably throwing an error and causing the rest of your code to not execute.

Comment: Like @Evilzebra said - there's no "s" in "getElementById". That's probably the reason why everything after this syntax error won't execute.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for pointing that out. Feel silly for making such a syntax error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`document.getElementsById` isn't a function. The code throws an exception (which should be visible in your Console) and then stops.

The function doesn't have an `s` in it as it returns a single element (since an ID must be unique in a document).